# Simple procedure example does not work. why?

Tags: mysql, procedure

This procedure does not work. Please, tell me what is the matter?

```
drop procedure if exists while_do;
delimiter $$
 
CREATE PROCEDURE `while_do`()
BEGIN
  SET @p=0;
  WHILE @p<10 DO
    SET @p = @p + 1;
  END WHILE;
  SELECT @p;
END $$
 
DELIMITER ;  
call while_do();
```

ERROR:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' 
CREATE PROCEDURE `whilew_do`()
BEGIN
  SET @p=0;
  WHILE @p<10 DO
    SE' at line 1

Comment: Are you doing this from command line or something else? NB this works fine when submiitted in mysqlworkbench and heidisql query editors. Try without setting delimiters.

Comment: This procedure works fine, check [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kLZA91Xii6LSgGRkbPhNV6/0) and [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ulb0vurg).

Comment: I do it from phpMyAdmin. It means that there is something wrong with phpMyAdmin. What?

Comment: Refreshing phpMyAdmin did not help.
But in https://www.db-fiddle.com/ and heidisql it works .
Thanks to Ergest Basha and P.Salmon

Answer (score 1):

Your query works in phpMyAdmin (PMA), but with a few tweaks.

I'm assuming that SQL was pasted to the SQL tab?

What needs to change is to remove the lines with `delimiter`, as there is an input to specify the delimiter below the SQL text area:

[image]

1. Then modify the query to look like this instead:

   ```
   drop procedure if exists while_do;
   $$

   CREATE PROCEDURE `while_do`()
   BEGIN
     SET @p=0;
     WHILE @p<10 DO
       SET @p = @p + 1;
     END WHILE;
     SELECT @p;
   END;
   $$

   call while_do();
   $$
   ```
2. Change the delimiter in the input to `$$`:

[image]

3. Then run the query, the output will look like:

[image]

---

Alternatively, another way to create routines in PMA would be the `Routines` tab, and there would be no need to mess with the delimiter at all:

[image]

Below the routines list is:

[image]

Clicking the `Add routine` link will open a popup form. Fill out as shown, drop the parameter list:

[image]

Then after clicking the `Go` button, the new routine will be listed:

[image]

---

My version info:

[image]